# Personalized lock screen for Android

Tags: android, screen, locking

Hello I am looking for personalized screen locker for android phones, instead of typing numbers , user can flex fingers in a particular pattern and unlock the screen.
Any pointers/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own locker or just configuring your phone? Settings->Security->Unlock pattern. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am trying to write my own lcoker, which at first time will recognize the users finger movement pattern and store it to verify and unlock the screen upon same finger movement. 
(Say there are 4*4 buttons/cells). During registration mode , App is  waiting to sense user's finger movement, once done it will record/store the pattern and wait for user until it gets the required input. If successful, it unlocks the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at the Android source: [LockPatternUtils.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java) and [LockScreen.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_policies_base/blob/master/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java) for an idea of how to go about implementing your own.

Also interesting is the [android.gesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html) package which you can use to [create and save gestures](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).

Comment: How does the example on the link you provided relate to your question? If you are referring to the pass code unlock screen, then I am not sure the number picker widget in the example is what you want.

Comment: LockScreen.java can be found here as well, since that link doesn't lead to it: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/policies/base/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java