# Display Custom Information on Lock Screen In Android

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to custom LockScreen.

The default Lock screen is like this.[image: Default Lock Screen]

I want to modify this portion of the Lock Screen & Let all other things remain the same.
When user locks his phone, it should display custom information on that red box.

[image: I want to replace the red box portion with new information]

So far i have seen one app that does something similar to this things : [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&feature=search_result)

StackOverflow Search so far :

[Is there a way to override the lock pattern screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180654/is-there-a-way-to-override-the-lock-pattern-screen/3181119#3181119) which says not possible.

[Android Lock Screen Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget) (Kevin TeslaCoil's Answer) This really tells something

[Personalized lock screen for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000197/personalized-lock-screen-for-android) Dont understand what the source says.

How can i achieve that ?

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, you have to write your lockscreen, then disable the default one. You can listen for screen on and off events then disable the home button by basically making your custom locksceen a launcher.

This has been asked before here: [Developing a custom lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen)

And here: [Android Lockscreen API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181615/android-lockscreen-api)