# Android unlock screen programming

Tags: android, unlock

I need to create a new designed unlock screen for Android mobile

Which are the files I need to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000197/personalized-lock-screen-for-android

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure that you're not allowed to do it with Titanium.
It gaves you almost all native support but just in-app, you can't write the kind of stuff you're looking for.